# In the Redux tutorial, running index.js, how do I avoid "ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, babeljs

I am working through the redux tutorial listed on the official redux site [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html). When I run it, however, it produces an error. I'd like to know if there is a configuration issue I am missing.

I am trying to run the entry point, index.js, from node. That file looks like the following:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import todoApp from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

let store = createStore(todoApp)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

I am running it with this command:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets react,es2015 index.js
```

That results in this error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
/Users/dan/code/tutorial/redux-todo/index.js:29
), document.getElementById('root'));
   ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dan/code/tutorial/redux-todo/index.js:14:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at loader (/Users/dan/code/tutorial/redux-todo/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/dan/code/tutorial/redux-todo/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at /Users/dan/code/tutorial/redux-todo/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:159:24
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/dan/code/tutorial/redux-todo/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:160:7)
```

I am on OSX, using the version of npm and node installed by homebrew. The following modules are installed using npm:

```
react
react-dom
redux
react-redux
babel
babel-cli
babel-preset-es2015
babel-preset-jsx
```

Is there a configuration or a context issue I'm missing that would cause this error when running the script?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use babel to *compile* your code, not run it. `babel-node` compiles it first then tries to run it as a node script. The `document` object is only available in browser environments.

Try this instead:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel --presets react,es2015 index.js --outfile compiled.js
```

If this runs successfully, then `compiled.js` should contain the browser ready code and you can link to it from a HTML document to run it in a browser.

Comment: Babel-node will transpile the ES6 code to ES5 but will still execute the back-end node.js server. I would ask if the OP has an entry point HTML file. The tutorial quoted tends to have some rather large assumptions in the setup of the basic app while introducing redux.

Comment: @Paul Stoner That's probably because there's no need to learn Redux with React until you come up against the limitations of state management inside React. At that point, Babel will be a familiar tool.

Comment: Agreed. But looking at OP's code, it should work unless the root html is missing. or am I way off base?

Comment: @PaulStoner He needs to run it in a browser, not with server side JS.